# Modern version of WinDiff?

Tags: windows, vb6, diff

VB6 came with `WinDiff`.

Is there a free modern version of WinDiff available that is able to ignore case?

Comment: Check out BeyondCompare (http://www.scootersoftware.com/) as an example of a great comparison tool.

Comment: I am using [`WinMerge`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge) - it is free, and it is very intuitive to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with WinMerge and the WinDiff from the latest SDK, I also have SourceGear's free DiffMerge.

I use WinMerge (which hasn't changed for a while either -- don't ignore blank lines; that exercises bugs) most, especially its ability to open two blank editable pages and you can paste anything, such as from a Remote Desktop to a machine that does not have any visual diff installed, and the differences automatically (or manually if you prefer) update.

DiffMerge's feature I like is its display of differences, which seems to cater for spuriously different line breaks better.

And, to answer your question, the WinDiff from the latest SDK (or at least the one included with Visual Studio 2010), WinMerge, and DiffMerge can all ignore case.

Comment: Why does ignoring blank lines exercise bugs?

Comment: I don't know why (I haven't reviewed the code), just that there are bug reports with workarounds stating to turn off ignore blank lines; and I've seen at least some of those bugs myself.

Comment: Is the SDK version OK?  Why not just use that?

Comment: My comment re "don't ignore blank lines; that exercises bugs" is refering to WinMerge, which is on SourceForge. I don't know of any bugs in WinDiff.

Answer (score 2):

WinDiff is part of the Windows SDK, it still ships with it.  But no, the SDK is targeted to programmers that write code in case-sensitive languages, C and C++.

The source code of WinDiff was once part of the SDK samples.  You can still get it from [this web page](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm), assuming you're into hacking C code and have an old compiler laying around.  You'll need to adapt line.c, the line_gethashcode() and line_compare() functions.  Lower-casing the line is easiest.

Well, that was the programmer's answer.  Plenty of other fish in the sea, Beyond Compare typically gets a lot of nods.

Comment: -1: The WinDiff in modern versions of SDK (eg. 2010) are able to ignore case.